# SQL SMO - checking if a user is a server admin

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo, sqldmo

I want to check if the connected user is a SQL Server admin (in the sysadmin role) and wondering if this is this is the best way to do it?

```
private static bool IsUserAdmin(Server server)
{
   Login login = server.Logins[server.ConnectionContext.Login];
   return login.IsMember("sysadmin");
}
```

In SQL DMO (the COM based predecessor to SMO) there was a property that hung off the `SQLDMO.SQLServer` object called `IsServerAdmin`. I'm wondering if there's something similar in SMO but that I just haven't been able to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, actually I think yours is the best way to check if the current login is a SQL Server administrator (that then is a member of `sysadmin` role).

I have some experience with SMO and I found no other way better than this, also because there's no property similar to `IsServerAdmin` listed in the [SMO documentation related to the `Login` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.login.aspx).

If you want, you can execute a T-SQL query to know which SQL Server Logins are members of `sysadmin` role (that will give you the same results of C# code):

```
SELECT p.name AS [Name] ,r.type_desc,r.is_disabled,r.create_date , r.modify_date,r.default_database_name
FROM
sys.server_principals r
INNER JOIN sys.server_role_members m ON r.principal_id = m.role_principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals p ON
p.principal_id = m.member_principal_id
WHERE r.type = 'R' and r.name = N'sysadmin'
```

Comment: +1 for the T-SQL above. Always nice to get these snippets :-)